# Only grep for lines that only contain alphabetical characters

Tags: grep

**Question:** How can I grep for lines that ONLY have the following characters (all in lowercase)?

```
aábcdeéfghiíjklmnoóöőpqrstuúüűvwxyz
```

example:

INPUT:

```
árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép
árvíztűrő tü3körfúrógép
"árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép
```

OUTPUT:

```
árvíztűrő tükörfúrógép
```

Comment: `grep -x '[aábcdeéfghiíjklmnoóöőpqrstuúüűvwxyz ]\+'`

Comment: can you please post this as answer? :)

Comment: So, you mean "only lowercase letters ***and spaces***", right?

Comment: I removed the space from Costas answer, no space needed, thanks!

Comment: only the letters needed.

Comment: If you don't include space in the match set you'll match no rows at all

Comment: grep -x '[aábcdeéfghiíjklmnoóöőpqrstuúüűvwxyz]\+' this works for me :)

Comment: @freaking-good-question that doesn't match any of your example input data because you haven't included a space in your match set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep -x '[aábcdeéfghiíjklmnoóöőpqrstuúüűvwxyz ]\+'
```

- `-x` match pattern to whole line
- `[...]` list of symbols to match
- `+` symbol should present at least one